# Setting javascript variable to PHP array's specific index

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have a one (very) big PHP array (with 649 indexes). 
I want to set a javascript variable to specific index of it and that index will depend on another variable. Is there any way? I know i can copy whole PHP array into JavaScript Array using `json_encode($phpArray)` , but i don't want whole array to be loaded on client side
(for speed and some sort of security).

```php
 $phpArray[0] = "i am first element";
 $phpArray[1] = "i am second element";
 /* ......... */
 $phpArray[100] = "i am 100th element";
```

and now, let us say, i want to get second element of `$phpArray` ? how can i do it?

Comment: `$first =$phpArray[0]; $second = $phpArray[1];`

Comment: `echo "var myJSvar = '" . $phpArray[1] . "';";`

Comment: You could send an ajax-request to fetch the specific entry. But the security will not be better since you are sending the index and that can be altered by the user as well. I do not think that performance is an issue if your array only contains strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery `$.post` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var my_var;
  $.post("my-php-page.php",
         {my_index: 1},
         function(data) {
           my_var = data.my_value;
         },
         "json");
});
```

**my-php-page.php**

```
<?php
 $phpArray[0] = "i am first element";
 $phpArray[1] = "i am second element";
 /* ......... */
 $phpArray[100] = "i am 100th element";
 echo json_encode(array("my_value" => $phpArray[$_POST['my_index']]));
?>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: i don't understood your ans. completely, however i got some idea, but that `my_index: 1,` wouldn't me always one, it can be anything (variable), selected by user.

Comment: This is just an example.. you can put there a combo box value and it becomes dynamically